# Ormlite Where-Contains Fails

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm attempting to query my db using `Enumerable.Contains` inside a `SqlExpressionVisitor.Where`clause. When the lambda is compiled, I'm getting a null reference exception.

When the visitor makes it to `foreach (Object e in inArgs)` (currently line 1067) inside `SqlExpressionVisitor.VisitArrayMethodCall`, it chokes because `inArgs` is null. The following is my sample that causes the error. I don't understand lambdas/expressions well enough to know why this is happening.

**So my questions is**, am I not using the `Where` clause properly or is this a bug?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connectionFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True", SqlServerDialect.Provider);
        SetupDb(connectionFactory);           

        using (var db = connectionFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            var numbersToSelect = new int[2] { 1, 2 };
            db.Select<SomeObject>(e => e.Where(o => numbersToSelect.Contains(o.Number)));
        }
    }

    static void SetupDb(IDbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
    {
        using (var db = connectionFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            db.DropTable<SomeObject>();
            db.CreateTable<SomeObject>();
            db.Insert(new SomeObject { Number = 1 });
            db.Insert(new SomeObject { Number = 2 });
            db.Insert(new SomeObject { Number = 3 });
            db.Insert(new SomeObject { Number = 4 });
            db.Insert(new SomeObject { Number = 5 });
        }
    }
}

class SomeObject
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

---

After a little more digging, it turns out calling the compiled method is returning an `int[]` which causes the cast to `object[]` to be null. Casting to `IEnumerable` fixes my specific issue.

Changed

```
var getter = lambda.Compile();
var inArgs = getter() as object[];
```

to

```
var getter = lambda.Compile();
var inArgs = getter() as IEnumerable;
```

Not sure what sort of implications this has though (if any). Still looking for some guidance.

Comment: It looks like there was an update to the ORMLite repository about [6 hours ago](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/9f0b0e8cfa4410da5d288bf754ba6538805cbec0) related to this specific issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug. It's been fixed for the sqlite visitor and the sql visitor as of [commit 9f0b0e8](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/9f0b0e8cfa4410da5d288bf754ba6538805cbec0) Thanks @mythz.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using Contains, use Sql.In

`db.Select<SomeObject>(e => e.Where(o => Sql.In(o.Number,numbersToSelect)));`

Comment: `Sql.In` doesn't work on non-sql stores (`List<T>`). The actual code I have is in a service layer which calls repositories that take an expression as a parameter.